# Makefile: make clean invokes other rules without depending on them

Tags: makefile, rules

I wrote a makefile which behaves oddly. You can find it here: http://pastebit.com/pastie/8215

Basically every time i type make clean, make executes rules on lines 44, 40 and 25 (in this order). It is very odd since nothing depends on clean and clean doesn't have any dependecies.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add this to the bottom of your Makefile:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include .depend
endif
```

and remove the "include .depend" from line 29.

Comment: +1 doesn't need to be at the bottom -- you could just replace line 29 with this.  Also the `-` is not strictly necessary -- it just supresses warnings about `.depend` not exiting, which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you `include .depend` on line 29, which depends on `$(SRCLIST)`, which in turn is made using rules that you've mentioned in your question.

From [How Makefiles Are Remade](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) chapter:

> To this end, after reading in all makefiles, make will consider each as a goal target and attempt to update it. If a makefile has a rule which says how to update it (found either in that very makefile or in another one) or if an implicit rule applies to it (see Using Implicit Rules), it will be updated if necessary.

Also I guess invoking `make -d` would tell you something more on that.